# django cms shows blank pages on using a restored postgres db dump

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-cms, pg-dump

In the process of migrating a site to another host I made a postgres dump using the commands

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -F c -a -v -f /tmp/cms_2015.dump cms
```

and restored it using

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -d cms -v /tmp/cms_2015.dump --disable-triggers
```

I am convinced the problem has to do with the database since with the same code base it works on the initial host but no page data is displayed on the second host.

Currently there are no js errors and I use 
    django 1.7
    djangocms 3.0.7

I appreciate any efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone ever gets to this point the solution to my problems was:

1. Dump db with data only from the working host.
2. Clear the required new db
3. Use django's migrations to create the tables
4. Finally restore the data with triggers disabled